# Destructuring in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code

```
let obj={ n:1, j:'test' };
obj[j] = 'new val' ;
let { j } = obj;
alert(j);//'test'
```

Why is the output still old value.

Comment: Because you can't access `obj[j]` as no `j` was defined. Try `obj.j`

Comment: When I run it I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined`; `obj` is unchanged.

Comment: To add, maybe you should use `obj['j']` or `obj.j`

Comment: Got it, was a useless question. Just started javascript and got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd line, when you want to set `obj[j]`, `j` is not defined because you want to access `obj.j` via a separate variable, called `j`.

```
obj[j] = 'new val';
```

If you want to access `obj.j`, you have 2 options in JavaScript:

- via .key: `obj.j`
- via ['key']: `obj['j']`

---

Use JavaScript's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```js
let obj = { n: 1, j: 'test' };
obj.j = 'new val';

// access one of them
(() => {
  let { j } = obj;
  console.log(j); // 'test'

  let { n } = obj;
  console.log(n); // 1
})();

// access multiple
(() => {
  let { n, j } = obj;
  console.log(n, j); // 1, 'test'
})();

// access via rest
(() => {
  let { ...rest } = obj;
  console.log(rest); // { n: 1, j: 'test' }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't show the initial value of `j`, I will assume it is `undefined`, so what you are doing is setting `obj[undefined]`, which won't work. Either of these should do what you meant:

```
obj.j = 'new val'
obj['j'] = 'new val'
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a grammatical mistake

a right way is:

```
let obj={ n:1, j:'test' };
obj.j = 'new val' ;
let { j } = obj;
alert(j);//'test'
```

or

```
let obj={ n:1, j:'test' };
let foo = 'j'
obj[foo] = 'new val' ;
let { j } = obj;
alert(j);//'test'
```

so, the words in [] means a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around `j`, otherwise it is seen as a variable.

```
let obj={ n:1, j:'test' };
obj['j'] = 'new val' ;
alert(obj);//'test'
```